# grails app, using java-apns

Tags: java, iphone, grails, apple-push-notifications

I have a grails app, and I am using the java-apns 0.1.5 jar! I have a device key, which already uninstall my app from it, so my question is, should I receive same feedback from the API saying that device is not enable anymore?
My code is the following:

```
apnsService = APNS.newService()
        .withCert(pathToCertificate, password)
        .withFeedbackDestination("feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com",2196)
        .withSandboxDestination()
        .build();

apnsService.start();

Map<String, Date> inactiveDevices = apnsService.getInactiveDevices();
log.debug inactiveDevices

.....
```

the think is that, the variable inactiveDevices is always empty! why? if I uninstall the app from the device?! am I missing some think in the client(device) side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Sandbox destination, the feedback service may not
report info correctly. This is a known bug with a known workaround,
check the [mailing list thread](http://groups.google.com/group/easyapns/browse_thread/thread/19b2d523efd1c2b3/bb12467733c638db?#bb12467733c638db)

> The problem comes from the "Sandbox"  APNs Feedback server, probably a
>   bug. Here is the solution if anyone  has the same problem:
>
> Create a dummy app id in the program portal, enable development push 
>   notifications on it Create and download the associated provisioning 
>   profile Create a new xcode project, and invoke the 
>   registerForRemoteNotificationTypes method on start. Install the dummy 
>   app on your device. At this point, you should have two DEVELOPMENT 
>   apps running on your device: the original app and the dummy app. Both 
>   should be registered to receive push notifications. Uninstall the 
>   original app, and try to send a push notification to that app. Invoke 
>   the feedback service, and you should receive data back.
>
> To resume, the Sandbox Feedbacks server needs TWO DEVELOPMENT Apps 
>   registered on the SAME iPhone to work.  This manipulation is not
>   necessary for the production phase as the  "Production" APNs Feedback
>   server works fine.

I would recommend just switching to test feedback with the production servers.
Please either test with the production servers or use the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hello Guys i have done push using grails APNS also with simple java lib.

1. With  Grails  : here is code snippet for APNS using grails

Hello Guys i have done push using grails APNS.
there are one Important point to remember
1. Proper apple certificate, Apple approved.: Apple approve certificate after 24 hours.
here is my code
1. in config.groovy
environments {
development {
apns {
pathToCertificate = "/Users/sarbogast/Desktop/APNs_development_certificates.p12"
password = "password"
environment = "sandbox"
}
} test {
apns {
pathToCertificate = "/usr/local/myapp/APNs_development_certificates.p12"
password = "password"
environment = "sandbox"
}
} production {
apns {
pathToCertificate = "/usr/local/myapp/APNs_production_certificates.p12"
password = "password"
environment = "production"
}
}
}2. i create a service and here is my service class code  def sendMessageToDevices() { List<string> aa = new ArrayList<string>() aa.add("Testing") def payload = APNS.newPayload() .badge(1) .localizedKey("key") .localizedArguments(aa) .sound("default") log.error(payload.length()) if (payload.isTooLong()){ log.info("Message is too long: " + payload.length()) } try { apnsService.testConnection() apnsService.push("Device token here", payload.build() ) } catch (Exception e) { log.error("Could not connect to APNs to send the notification"+e.getMessage()) } }
here "key" is any message which will popup on device push
3. i called this method by controller method..
```